# Delete unused, unattached, unassociated resources Azure CLI

Tags: azure, devops, azure-cli, azure-nsg, azure-public-ip

I'm trying to list unused, unattached, and unassociated resources inside Azure using Azure CLI.

So far, I've got unmanaged disks using the command:

```
unmanagedDiskNames=$(az disk list -g $rgName --query "[?(managedBy==null)].name" -o tsv)
```

I've got unattached Network interfaces using the command:

```
unattachedNicsIds=$(az network nic list -g $rgName --query "[?(virtualMachine==null)].id" -o tsv)
```

I'm having issued listing Public IPs and Network security groups. Tried to get public IPs using the command (it not worked):

```
unassociated_publicIPs=$(az network public-ip list -g "Technology-RG" --query "[?(IpConfiguration==null)].id" -o tsv)
```

Can you help me get unassociated public IPs and NSGs?
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding this here.  I'm working on deleting unused resources and I've used this code to make a simple bash script to delete anything unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the command for listing unassociated public IPs using Azure CLI is:

```
az network public-ip list -g $rgName --query "[?(ipConfiguration==null)].id" -o tsv
```

The command for listing unassociated network security groups IPs using Azure CLI is:

```
az network nsg list -g $rgName --query "[?(subnets==null) && (networkInterfaces==null)].id" -o tsv
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a case sensitive issue, your "IpConfiguration==null" has uppercase "I", replace it to lowercase "ipConfiguration==null" and then you get the right result.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestions about NSGs? Where can I list all available queries of resources when using the --query inside the CLI?

Comment: In this case NSG is associated to either SUBNET or NETWORKINTERFACES, so you can filter by ""networkInterfaces": null and""subnets": null". You should try something like that to get starts (az network nsg list -g site1 --query "[?networkInterfaces == null && subnets == null].id" -o tsv)